# How can I get 2018 instead of 1970 from new Date javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the full year of todays date.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var identy = "2-5";
    var month = identy.split("-")[0];
    var day = identy.split("-")[1];
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    let gdday = new Date(year- + month + -day);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = gdday;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to do this only by this method.I want to display 2018-02-05.But it shows 1970-01-01.I use this code in my project and this is just a demo.Thank you in advance :)

Comment: check this line: `let gdday = new Date(year- + month + -day);` there's something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *comma* `,` instead of `+` and `-`

```
let gdday = new Date( year , (+month - 1) , +day);
```

**Note that**

- *month* is converted to `Number` and is `0` based value
- `day` is converted to a `Number` first.

Comment: `(+month - 1)` can be `month - 1`. There is no need to convert the day to number. You could also do `var gdday = new Date(); gdday.setMonth(month - 1, day)`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the full year of todays date.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var identy = "2-5";
    var month = identy.split("-")[0];
    var day = identy.split("-")[1];
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    let gdday = new Date(year, month, day);//Change This line
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = gdday;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```